# Pandas: how to Identify lines with specific value in column x, and use other values in same line as variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to identify a row containing 1 in column x, and use other values in the same row as variables. Then I would like to identify a row in a different dataframe which contains the variables, and delete the row.

df1:

```
z  y  x
--------
3  3  0
5  4  1
```

df2:

```
a  b  c  d  e
--------------
5  4  p  p  p  <-- Delete this row
3  3  p  p  p
```

Comment: How do you connect col names `z,y` to `a,b` ?

Comment: Please provide sample data in the form of copy/pastable form so people can easily show you examples. You need to read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing .

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it, if you are looking for a scalable version, with more than just 2 rows in `df1` and `df2`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"z":[3,5], "y": [3,4], "x": [0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[5,4], "b":[4,3], "c": ["p","p"], "d": ["p","p"], "e": ["p","p"]})

df1_set = df1[df1.x == 1]
idx = []

for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df1_set)):
        if (df2.a.iloc[i], df2.b.iloc[i])  == (df1_set.z.iloc[j], df1_set.y.iloc[j]):
            idx.append(i)

df2_set = df2.drop(idx)
```

The `dataframes` look like this:

```
df1_set
Out[50]: 
   z  y  x
1  5  4  1

df2_set
Out[51]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
1  4  3  p  p  p
```

Here `df1_set` is the selective `df` from `df1`, which has value of `x = 1`, and then `df2_set` if the final output that you are seeking.

**Explanation**:

1. Find out the rows with `x = 1` in `df1`
2. Run loops on `df1` and `df2` to
   remove each element in `df2` where the set `z` and `y` from `df1_set`
   matches `a` and `b` from `df2`

Answer (score 0):

For both `DataFrame` you can create the column that will be used to match both `DataFrame` together, you need a column that contains a `tuple` with the different values

Then remove from the main dataframe, the rows where `(a,b)` is contained in the valus that com from the second dataframe

```
df_idx = DataFrame({'z': [3, 5], 'y': [3, 4], 'x': [0, 1]})
df = DataFrame({'a': [5, 3], 'b': [4, 3], 'c': ['A', 'A'], 'd': ['A', 'A'], 'e': ['A', 'A']})

df_idx['match'] = df_idx[['z', 'y']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
df['match']     = df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

selectors = df_idx[df_idx.x == 1]
result = df[~df.match.isin(selectors['match'].tolist())]


>>> print(df_idx)
   z  y  x   match
0  3  3  0  (3, 3)
1  5  4  1  (5, 4)

>>> print(df)
   a  b  c  d  e   match
0  5  4  A  A  A  (5, 4)
1  3  3  A  A  A  (3, 3)

>>> print(selectors['match'].tolist())
[(5, 4)]

>>> print(result)
   a  b  c  d  e   match
1  3  3  A  A  A  (3, 3)
```